# Use of 'full' in MATLAB function arguments

Tags: matlab, function

In some libraries, e.g. the one below from CVX, I notice the argument `full`. I can't seem to find any documentation that explains what this is and why it's there. Can anyone explain?

EDIT: As suggested, here is a [link to the function](https://github.com/cvxr/CVX/blob/master/lib/cvx_isaffine.m). Please note that this is the entire function.

```
function y = cvx_isaffine( x, full ) 
narginchk(1,2);
if nargin == 1,
    y = true;
else
    y = true( size( x ) );
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function, the test `if nargin == 1` checks to see if the second input argument, `full` is given. If it is, the output is a logical array of same size as `x`. If it is not, then the output is a scalar logical array.

That is,

```
M = randn(10,3);
cvx_isaffine(M)
```

returns `true`, whereas

```
cvx_isaffine(M,1)
```

returns a 10x3 array with all elements are `true`.

You can fill in whatever you want for this second argument, as its value is not used anywhere. Just the presence of the 2nd argument is a flag for a change in behavior.

The function seems to not be documented because it is meant for internal use, and not for use by the end-user.